# fe_sendauth: no password supplied error in postgresql + laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, migration

I am trying to run database migrations in a Laravel application. However, I keep getting the error:

```
[PDOException]                                         
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

After some research, I edited my pg_hba.conf file by adding an entry in the last line (below). I then reloaded the database's config settings:

`SELECT pg_reload_conf();`

I tried to run the migration again but I am still getting the same `no password supplied` error. Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     user                                  trust
#host    replication     user          127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     user          ::1/128                 trust
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust <--- this is my entry
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? In my case this started happening today and it's totally random... sometimes it connects, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Also stuck with this issue and can't figure out why

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue -- somehow I had set a global environment variable DB_PASSWORD that was taking precedence over my DB_PASSWORD as set in my .env file. That global environment variable was set to empty, thus the system wasn't lying -- I really was not passing a password :)  I fixed this by running the following command:

unset DB_PASSWORD

Then all was good.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the `pg_hba.conf` file, you need to restart Postgres for the changes to take effect.

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: in my case (ubuntu 19.04) it was `systemctl restart postgres`

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5.6 try socket connection not localhost - it worked for me.

```
host=/var/run/postgresql
```

Mind that `local` in _pg_hba.conf_ is not equivalent to `localhost`.

In Debian its located in: */var/run/postgresql* (other place is under */tmp*)

```
$mydb = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=mydb;host=/var/run/postgresql;user=myuser');
```