# How to connect Postgresql database in Slim framework with PDO?

Tags: php, postgresql, slim

I work with MYSQL database in slim framework. Its perfectly worked.
But going to connect Postgresql, It not connected as well.

Here is the sample Coding: (settings.php)

```
    declare(strict_types=1);
    use App\Application\Settings\Settings;
    use App\Application\Settings\SettingsInterface;
    use DI\ContainerBuilder;
    use Monolog\Logger;
    
    return function (ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    
        $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
            SettingsInterface::class => function () {
                return new Settings([
                    'displayErrorDetails' => true, // Should be set to false in production
                    'logError'            => true,
                    'logErrorDetails'     => true,
                    'logger' => [
                        'name' => 'slim-app',
                        'path' => isset($_ENV['docker']) ? 'php://stdout' : __DIR__ . '/../logs/app.log',
                        'level' => Logger::DEBUG,
                    ],
                        "db" =>
                               [
                                'driver'   => 'pgsql',
                                'host'     => 'localhost',
                                'port'     => '5433',
                                'database' => 'test_db',
                                'username' => 'postgres',
                                'password' => 'password',
                                'prefix'   => '',
                                'schema'   => 'public',
                            ]
    
                    ]);
            }
        ]);
};
```

Here is the code : (dependencies.php)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use App\Application\Settings\SettingsInterface;
use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

return function (ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
        LoggerInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
            $settings = $c->get(SettingsInterface::class);

            $loggerSettings = $settings->get('logger');
            $logger = new Logger($loggerSettings['name']);

            $processor = new UidProcessor();
            $logger->pushProcessor($processor);

            $handler = new StreamHandler($loggerSettings['path'], $loggerSettings['level']);
            $logger->pushHandler($handler);

            return $logger;
        },
         PDO::class => function (ContainerInterface $c)
          {
 
            $settings = $c->get(SettingsInterface::class);
 
            $dbSettings = $settings->get("db");
 
            $host = $dbSettings['host'];
            $dbname = $dbSettings['database'];
            $username = $dbSettings['username'];
            $password = $dbSettings['password'];
            $port = $dbSettings['port'];
            $dsn = new PDO ("pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname");
           return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

        },

    ]);
};
```

Here checking for database connection : (routes.php)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use App\Application\Actions\User\ListUsersAction;
use App\Application\Actions\User\ViewUserAction;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Interfaces\RouteCollectorProxyInterface as Group;

return function (App $app) {
    $app->options('/{routes:.*}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        // CORS Pre-Flight OPTIONS Request Handler
        return $response;
    });

    $app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->getBody()->write('Hello world!');
        return $response;
    });

    $app->group('/users', function (Group $group)
    {
        $group->get('', ListUsersAction::class);
        $group->get('/{id}', ViewUserAction::class);
    });

    $app->post('/db-select', function (Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $db = $this->get(PDO::class);
        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login");
        $sth->execute();

        $data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $payload = json_encode($data);
        $response->getBody()->write($payload);
        return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    });

};
```

If I run the command such as `localhost:8000/db-select` Its give me the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": {
        "type": "SERVER_ERROR",
        "description": "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied"
    }
}
```

I worked the sample code for MYSQL it worked perfect.
What else missed for Postgresql connection?

Answer (score 0):

Check extension for PostgreSQL is enabled

extension=pdo_pgsql

Also you may take help fromm this question

[fe_sendauth: no password supplied error in postgresql + laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821417/fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied-error-in-postgresql-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bug:

```php
$dsn = new PDO ("pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname");

return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

Try this:

```php
return new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```